# Filter data based on current date + 365 days in Django Rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am trying to build a web app. Part of the requirement is when the user clicks on a time interval like "1 year", he can view all the upcoming movies in one year.

When the user clicks on "1 year" it should trigger a filter which displays movies from today till next year. How is it possible in django ?

I want to make a filter similar to this logic -

```
class sales_plot(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        interval = json.loads(request.body).get('interval')
        queryset = MovieList.objects.filter(date_of_relase= current_date + interval)
        serialize = serializer_name(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serialize.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

This is my model.py -

```
class MovieList(models.Model):
    Movie_id = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)
    date_of_release = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'movie_list'
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

convert interval to date object and current date and interval and query all objects which have date greater than or equal to the `interval + current date`

```py
from django.utils import timezone
from dateutil.parser import parse

class sales_plot(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        interval = parse(request.data.get("interval") or '00:00:00')
        future_date = timezone.now() + interval
        queryset = model_name.objects.filter(date_of_relase__gte=future_date)
        serialize = serializer_name(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serialize.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Packages: https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [***range***](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#range)

```
import datetime
interval = datetime.datetime.strptime('29-05-2019', "%d-%m-%Y").date()
# datetime.date(2019, 5, 29)
current_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
# datetime.date(2019, 9, 17)

queryset = model_name.objects.filter(date_of_relase__range=(current_date ,interval))
```